# How to add new grid rows without clearing existing data

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Code successfully adds new rows to the gridview on the button click, but clears all entered values in existing rows. I understand that, the existing data should be stored into a ViewState, but I do not know where/how to achieve this.

ASPX:

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvCommissions" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
     CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True">                
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="S.NO" ItemStyle-Width="5%">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:Label ID="lblSno" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:Label>
     </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="NAME" ItemStyle-Width="30%">
     <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Width="98%"></asp:TextBox>
     </ItemTemplate>
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CODE BEHIND:

```
DataTable dt;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       if(ViewState["gvCommissions"] != null) 
         dt = (DataTable)ViewState["gvCommissions"];
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            GridViewStructure();
            AddNewRow();
        }
        else
        {
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["gvCommissions"];
        }

        ViewState["gvCommissions"] = dt;  
    }

    private void GridViewStructure()
    {
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("sno");
        dt.Columns.Add("name");
    }            

    private void AddNewRow()
    {            
        dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("sno");
        dt.Columns.Add("name");

        foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvCommissions.Rows)
        {
            DataRow drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow();
            drCurrentRow["sno"] = ((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblSno")).Text;
            drCurrentRow["name"] = ((TextBox)gvRow.FindControl("txtName")).Text;
            dt.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow);
        }

        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["sno"] = "";
        dr["name"] = "";

        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        gvCommissions.DataSource = dt;
        gvCommissions.DataBind();

    }

    protected void btnAddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddNewRow();            
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its Simple first check if there is any row in gridview then add rows value in datatable then add the empty row. As below.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {           
        AddNewRow();
    }        
}

private void AddNewRow()
{           
    DataTable dt = new DatatTable(); 
    dt.Columns.Add("sno");
    dt.Columns.Add("name");
    foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvCommissions.Rows)
    {
        DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["sno"] = ((Label)gvRow.FindControl("lblSno")).Text;
        dr["name"] = ((Label)gvRow.FindControl("txtName")).Text;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }

    DataRow dr1 = dt.NewRow();
    dr1["sno"] = "";
    dr1["name"] = "";
    dt.Rows.Add(dr1);

    gvCommissions.DataSource = dt;
    gvCommissions.DataBind();

}


protected void btnAddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AddNewRow();            
}
```

Comment: It did not work:(...and moreover, its adding double the existing rows with every click. Should we clear/null dt before storing values of each row?

Comment: Yes u have to Clear DatatTable before inserting  data in That.

Comment: Ah. No Luck. Creating a new datatable wasnt enough as it was unable to find the column names. So I called 'GridViewStructure();' instead and the page now loads without errors and also adds rows, but the original issue stil remains....clears existing data. Thanks for helping though

Comment: Remove GridViewStructure() function Add that three line in AddNewRow() Function.

Comment: Not using viewstate anymore. Followed ur code as it is. Still no luck

Comment: @Raghubar....Thank you very much. Your soln. worked. The problem was with the missing 'Eval' in the columns' item template in the design page. I had to add them for each column: <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="lblSno" runat="server" Width="98%" Text='<%# Eval("sno")%>'></asp:Label> </ItemTemplate>

Answer (score 1):

You missed one part. Each time the page is loaded, you are saving the table to view state, and forgot to use it!

Try to retrieve it from viewstate at page load like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(ViewState["gvCommissions"] != null) dt = (DataTable)ViewState["gvCommissions"];
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        GridViewStructure();
        AddNewRow();
    }
    else
    {
        dt = (DataTable)ViewState["gvCommissions"];
    }

    ViewState["gvCommissions"] = dt;  
}
```

One thing I would add, it is not a good idea to save the table in view state.

Comment: Thank you. Shouldn't the first if condition be placed in the else part? viz..                                                                else                                                                {                                                                     if(ViewState["gvCommissions"] !=  null                            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["gvCommissions"]        }                                                    I have edited my question with the new additions..Still not working